# How to show that $\sum_{N=n}^{100} \frac{\frac{4}{9}^N}{(N-n)!(100-N)!} = \frac{\frac{4}{13}^n\frac{13}{9}^{100}}{(100-n)!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, summation

I am trying to show that for $n\geq 0$,

$$
\sum_{N=n}^{100} \frac{\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^N}{(N-n)!(100-N)!} = \frac{\left(\frac{4}{13}\right)^n\left(\frac{13}{9}\right)^{100}}{(100-n)!}
$$

Is there a simple way or a trick to calculate this summation?

Comment: Is it really fractions, the whole way through, or binomial coefficients?

Comment: @The Count It is actually fractions

Comment: Ok, cool. Just wanted to check. I bow out to the others, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac1{(N-n)!(100-N)!}=\frac1{(100-n)!}\binom{100-n}{100-N}\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{N=n}^{100}\frac{\left(\frac49\right)^N}{(N-n)!(100-N)!}&=\frac1{(100-n)!}\sum_{N=n}^{100}\left(\frac49\right)^N\binom{100-n}{100-N}\\\\
&=\frac1{(100-n)!}\sum_{k=0}^{100-n}\binom{100-n}k\left(\frac49\right)^{100-k}\\\\
&=\frac1{(100-n)!}\left(\frac49\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{100-n}\binom{100-n}k\left(\frac49\right)^{(100-n)-k}\\\\
&=\frac1{(100-n)!}\left(\frac49\right)^n\left(1+\frac49\right)^{100-n}\\\\
&=\frac1{(100-n)!}\left(\frac49\right)^n\left(\frac{13}9\right)^{100}\left(\frac9{13}\right)^n\\\\
&=\frac1{(100-n)!}\left(\frac4{13}\right)^n\left(\frac{13}9\right)^{100}\;.
\end{align*}$$

In the second step I substituted $k=100-N$, and in the fourth I applied the binomial theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I made a small typo, I meant to have $\left(\frac{4}{13}\right)^n$ instead of $\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^n$ on the right hand side. I just changed it above, sorry!

Comment: @user321627: And I made a mistake in my original calculation. But what you have now is still wrong: it’s missing a factor.

Comment: M Scott, thanks a lot! The $9^n$ appears to cancel out and match what I have newly written above. Thanks for answer!

Comment: @user321627: Sorry! You’re quite right; I wasn’t paying enough attention.

Answer (score 2):

You want
$\sum_{N=n}^{100} \frac{\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^N}{(N-n)!(100-N)!} 
= \frac{\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)^n\left(\frac{13}{9}\right)^{100}}{(100-n)!}
$.

Let's get rid of 
the particular numbers
and look at
$
s(a, n, m)
=\sum_{N=n}^{m} \frac{a^N}{(N-n)!(m-N)!} 
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
s(a, n, m)
&=\sum_{N=n}^{m} \dfrac{a^N}{(N-n)!(m-N)!}\\
&=\sum_{N=0}^{m-n} \dfrac{a^{N+m}}{N!(m-N-n)!}\\
&=a^m\sum_{N=0}^{m-n} \dfrac{a^{N}}{N!(m-n-N)!}\\
&=a^m\dfrac1{(m-n)!}\sum_{N=0}^{m-n} \dfrac{a^{N}(m-n)!}{N!(m-n-N)!}\\
&=\dfrac{a^m}{(m-n)!}\sum_{N=0}^{m-n} a^N \binom{m-n}{N}\\
&=\dfrac{a^m}{(m-n)!}(1+a)^{m-n}\\
&=\dfrac{a^m(1+a)^{m-n}}{(m-n)!}\\
\end{array}
$

Letting
$a=\dfrac49$
and
$m=100$,
we get
$s(a, m, n)
=\dfrac{(\frac49)^{100}(\frac{13}{9})^{100-n}}{(100-n)!}
=\dfrac{(\frac49)^{100}(\frac{13}{9})^{100}(\frac{9}{13})^{n}}{(100-n)!}
$
which does not agree
with your result.

So one of us is wrong.

Comment: I changed my earlier result, there was a typo. It seems that it still differs from your answer. Is the change of variables result in your third equation correct?